# Determining search query of guest user

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

In my app, there's a requirement to track search queries, which individuals to the app. The point here is to track specifically individuals/search_queries, i.e. I want to be able to say:

```
User 10.20.30.40 (IP is derived from client, ok) came to my website
from Google's search results page of 'hello world' query
```

**Is that even possible?**

I investigated the problem a bit. It turned out, that when the user on Google Search result page clicks a link and gets to the underlying page, the referer doesn't contain the search query. Say, for example, I entered a "Hello world" query...

1. I open google and enter a "Hello world" query;
2. I see a serach result page with a link to wikipedia on top; I follow it
3. I enter "document.referrer" in consonle to see:

   ```
   http://www.google.com.ua/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CGkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fru.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FHello%2C_world!&ei=HZ0fUIXTIordtAau54GwAQ&usg=AFQjCNHSAHv8NwVNdaxMvh0OhIxs6Zb1rQ&sig2=a8tEGTBNcFWOPykloXj_Xg
   ```

There's a `&q=` param with a blank value, preventing me to figure out the query the user entered.

I believe Google internally uses some of the query params (i.e. `ved`, `ei`, `usg` or `sig2`) from the URL above to keep track of query used to get to the site, and thus gatehr the statistics about which queries are used mostly to the get to the website. I couldn't find any information regarding how to use them.

In the meantime, Google Analytics would only gather a general statistics, not for individuals. Yet I noticed that there's an ability to use [Custom Variables](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets/customvars). Is it possible to use them somehow in order to track query the user came with? If so, wouldn't it be a violation of Google Analytics [Terms Of Service](http://www.google.com.ua/analytics/tos.html)?

So again: **is there a way to know a search query one came to the site with?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. Google erases the value of `q` parameter, so instead of

```
`?q=search+query`
```

one always observs.

```
`?q=`
```

Though, Google provides another way (the so called `convinient one`) to know which queries were used to come to your website: Google Analytics.

Also, it's impossible to track `user_ip/search_query` pair due to Google Analytics [`ToS`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095225/tracking-individual-users-with-google-analytics-custom-variables).